java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - eatg (File :- com.google.android.gms@243530018@24.35.30 (100300-668017056):5 )- Device status - 100% in background
The crash is happening in internal class of google play services. All the crashes are happening in background. Device status - 100% in background. Crash started from the last 5 days.
All the google play services libraries are also upto-date.
Attaching stack trace below.
Stack Trace :
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Leatg;
       at anqf.d(:com.google.android.gms@243530018@24.35.30 (100300-668017056):5)
       at ajso.<clinit>(:com.google.android.gms@243530018@24.35.30 (100300-668017056):9)
       at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@243530018@24.35.30 (100300-668017056):49)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:28)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zze.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzi.selectModule(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzef.zzf(zzef.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzcx.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.1:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.1:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Also, attaching the device status image

I was expecting to find some resolution by updating the google play services libraries. But it did not help.

Same problem appeared suddenly in our crashlytics. Please help.
